# Remove zombie foreign keys in MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, foreign-keys, schema

I'm trying to build a MySQL database gradually, by generation using JPA and Eclipse-Link. Along the way, I've changed some relationships `@ManyToOne`, `@OneToOne` etc.

I now have a situation where I have some spurious foreign keys: the tables don't exist, but the referenced tables still do. I think the original tables were cross-reference tables generated by EclipseLink but are no longer around.

The issue is, I cannot delete these referenced tables. I get an error like this:

```
mysql> drop table PRODUCTDO;
ERROR 3730 (HY000): Cannot drop table 'PRODUCTDO' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'PRODUCTDO_DISTRIBUTIONCENTERPRODUCTDO_ProductDo_ID' on table 'PRODUCTDO_DISTRIBUTIONCENTERPRODUCTDO'.
```

If I run:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

then I can delete the table, but the constraint still remains. Even if I drop the database and create it again, the constraint is still there:

```
mysql> SELECT    TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SCO';
+---------------------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME                            | COLUMN_NAME                  | CONSTRAINT_NAME                                    | REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME       | REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME |
+---------------------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+
| PRODUCTDO_DISTRIBUTIONCENTERPRODUCTDO | ProductDo_ID                 | PRODUCTDO_DISTRIBUTIONCENTERPRODUCTDO_ProductDo_ID | PRODUCTDO                   | ID                     |
| PRODUCTDO_DISTRIBUTIONCENTERPRODUCTDO | distributionCenterProduct_ID | PRDCTDDSTRBTIONCENTERPRODUCTDOdstrbtnCntrProductID | DISTRIBUTIONCENTERPRODUCTDO | ID                     |
+---------------------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**How can I get rid of these zombie constraints?**

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to recreate the table and foreign key then I was able to delete it.